# how to select a particular row with column value in magento

Tags: magento, model, entity-attribute-value

Normal sql syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMNVALUE="OUR VALUE"
```

After loading the model

```
$company1 = $this->companyFactory->create();
```

company1 module is loaded

How we to select the rows with our column value?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by value using `addFieldToFilter('column',value)`

full code :

`$model=Mage::getModel('catalog/product)->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status',1);`

here 1 is your value